# how to save all messages in mutt

Tags: mutt

How to save all messages using mutt ? I want to do a backup copy of my inbox from a imap server to a folder on my pc in maildir style not mbox.I selected all the messages pressing T button and then .* , the messages get a * , but when I press s for saving and selected the path it saves only one message.

Answer (score 0):

I found it , it was simply ;s after tagging all

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).